# I'm trying to learn a and pass parameters to api in JS

Tags: javascript, api

Still new to API usage and how to pass parameters this is my code so far.
I've tried watching some videos and couldn't quite figure it out. Though i know this community can definitely give me some pointers. Thank you in advance :)

```
function AutoFillApi(){

 var url = "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/autocomplete";
 jsonInit(url,"q=flame/format")


}
function jsonInit(url,xpath){

 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
 var context = response.getContentText();
 var json = JSON.parse(context);

 var patharray = xpath.split("/");

 console.log(patharray);

 var endres = json[xpath]
 console.log(endres);
 return endres

}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what is your specific question?

Comment: I am trying to pass parameters to the api and get a response the api is https://api.scryfall.com/cards/autocomplete. Requires a string to be sent as a Q variable.

Comment: And what **specific** problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is you need to

> I am trying to pass parameters to the api and get a response the api
>   is api.scryfall.com/cards/autocomplete. Requires a string to be sent
>   as a Q variable

so, append `xpath` to `url`

```
function AutoFillApi(){
   var url = "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/autocomplete";
   jsonInit(url, "flame", "json")
}

function jsonInit(url, query, format) {
  // append query and format to url after ?
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?q=" + query + "&format="+ format);
  var context = response.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(context);

  var endres = json.data;
  console.log(endres);
  return endres;
}
```

you can just get link to api [doc](https://scryfall.com/docs/api/cards/autocomplete)
`format` - is optional and can be only "json". you can avoid it actually

Comment: TY so much this worked. How would i get the return on the variable format?

Comment: I don't know what `format` is. Is a field of object? Is it in `json` variable?

Comment: ```q String  The string to autocomplete.
format String Optional The data format to return. This method only supports json.
pretty Boolean 
Optional
If true, the returned JSON will be prettified. Avoid using for production code.```